# Conditional Variances Question

Tags: self-study, variance, conditional-expectation

I am doing a question out of *Statistical Inference* by Casella and Berger, (4.58c). I am having trouble with the brief solution that my teacher discussed.

> $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with finite variances.
>
> Prove $V[Y - E(Y|X)] = E[V(Y|X)]$

I understand that by the conditional variance identity we can say

$$V[Y - E(Y|X)] = E[V[[Y-E(Y|X)] \ | \ X]] + V[E[[Y-E(Y|X)] \ | \ X ]]$$

but then the solutions from the teacher skip some steps and state this equals

$$ = E[V(Y|X)] +V[E(Y|X)-E(Y|X)]$$

Now I have very little intuition for dealing with double conditionals. My guess for how to fill in the blanks here is that, say for the following term, I should be able to "distribute out" the conditional like so:

$$E[V[[Y-E(Y|X)] \ | \ X]] = E \bigg[ V(Y|X) - V(E(Y|X)|X) \bigg]$$

or would this be completely off base? I feel like I have done something wrong since $V(X-Y) = V(X) + V(Y) - 2Cov(X,Y)$, but I am not sure how the conditional on $X$ would distribute out in a covariance function.

In another comment given to me, it was noted that "$E(Y|X)$ is constant w.r.t. the $(Y|X)$ distribution". But I am not exactly sure what to make of this. I am assuming somewhere I can take the variance of what ends up being a constant, and this will allow me to set it equal to 0 and simplify the problem.

---

So in short, any help or hints as to how to fill in the steps here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, by the **[Law of Total Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance)**: for any $Z, W$

$$V(Z) = E[V(Z\mid W)] + V[E(Z \mid W)]$$

Let $Z = Y - E(Y\mid X)$, and $W=X$.

Then

$$E(Z \mid W) = E\Big[Y - E(Y\mid X) \mid X\Big] = E(Y\mid X) - E(Y\mid X) = 0$$

So

$$V[E(Z \mid W) = V[E(Y - E(Y\mid X) \mid X) = V(0) = 0 $$.

So we are left only with the term

$$E[V(Z\mid W)]$$

Remember that $E(Y\mid X)$ is a function only of $X$ so $\forall X=x$, $E(Y\mid X=x)$ is a constant. Then

$$V(Z\mid W =w)=V\Big[Y-E(Y\mid X) \mid X=x\Big] = V\Big[Y \mid X =x\Big],\;\;\; \forall X=x$$

and so

$$V(Z\mid W)=V\Big[Y-E(Y\mid X) \mid X\Big] = V\Big[Y \mid X \Big].$$

Comment: I do not understand why we construct $e_X$. The expression after "The second term vanishes..." comes out to say $V[Y-E(Y|X)|X] = V[Y-E(Y|X)|X]$. The final lines are helpful though.

Comment: @KitsuneCavalry Neither do I. Two different versions of the answer got mixed up. Now corrected.